# Can we uniquely define for arbitrary, real-valued, finite sequence $X$, infinitely many pairs (real-valued $f(X)$, rank order of elements of $f(X)$)?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, set-theory, real-numbers, order-theory

For an arbitrary sequence $X$ of $n$ distinct real numbers, can we uniquely and exhaustively define a set of infinitely many pairs of the form: $[f_{j},$ order$(f_{j}(x))]$, where $f_{j}$ is a real-valued function that returns a sequence of $n$ real numbers, and is neither piecewise nor constant, and order$(.)$ returns the ascending rank order of the elements of $f_{j}(x)$?

For example, suppose $n = 4$ and $X = (.1,0,.2,44)$, and $f_{1}(x) = x^2 = (.01,0,.4,1936)$, $f_{2}(x) = (x - 2)^2 = (3.61, 4, 3.24, 1764)$, and so on. Then its pairs would be $[f_{1}, (2,1,3,4)], [f_{2}, (2,3,1,4)]$, and so on. If we define such pairs for $X$ and all possible $f_{j}$, must there be at least one other sequence $Y$ of $n$ distinct real numbers that, when plugged into all the same functions, gives all the same answers in terms of rank order of elements? Or will all $Y$ fail for at least one $f_{j}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a countable set $\cal F$ of functions that serve to uniquely identify every sequence of $n\ge 3$ real numbers in the manner you propose. Define $f_r$ by
$$f_r(x):= (x-r)^2,$$
and let ${\cal F}$ be the collection of all such $f_r$ as $r$ ranges over the rational numbers. Since
$$f_r(x) - f_r(x') = (x-x')(x+x'-2r),$$ for given slots $i$ and $j$ in the output vector you can deduce the value of $x_i+x_j$ by checking for each $r$ whether $f_r(x_i)$ ranks higher or lower than $f_r(x_j)$. (Specifically, there will be a flip in rank order when $2r$ passes the threshold $x_i+x_j$.)

So if $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a sequence of values , you can inspect the output vectors to determine the sum $x_i+x_j$ for every $i\ne j$.  If $n\ge3$, this knowledge is sufficient to deduce the individual values of each $x_i$ and $x_j$.

Comment: This is deeply interesting! It's particularly nice to see that, if you're only dealing with a subset of all possible real sequences of a given length, knowing something about the subset (max or min or mean, say) means you can limit the range of r. Is this a solution of your own invention, or is this a known result for an existing problem? I'd appreciate any leads you can give on related problems, like citations or theorems or notable examples, so I can explore further. Thanks!

Comment: This may be a known result for an existing problem, but I'm not aware of what that problem might be! I arrived at this solution after dispensing with more elaborate forms for $\cal F$, and eventually finding that the output of the quadratic family has the ability to "encode" every sum $x_i+x_j$. And you can drop the restriction to rational $r$ if you don't care about the size of the family. I'm curious to know the motivation for the original question -- what problem were you trying to solve?

Comment: Well, consider that this is a one-way function: It's computationally easy to check that a sequence of $n + 2$ integers ($n$ ranks plus $a$ and $b$ for rational number $r = a/b$) is consistent with a hidden sequence of $n$ real numbers. (Although, in practice, you'd use $n$ sequences of arbitrarily long random integer sequences.) It's computationally hard to construct an integer sequence that would pass that test without knowing the real-valued sequence, even if you have many thousands of such sequences generated from it to work from. So, $P \ne NP$. Interested in co-authoring the paper?

Comment: try this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416409/whats-the-probability-of-cracking-this-cipher-using-partial-information-about-t